# Is there a way to select all Objects in Salesforce that start with a value?

Tags: salesforce, soql

I can select all apex triggers by using

```
select id, name from ApexTrigger
```

and classes by using

```
select id, name from ApexClasses
```

but is there a way to select all objects ?

I have tried

```
select id, name from Objects  but doesnt seem to work ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOQL queries run on exactly one object.

If you need to perform a full-text search across multiple objects, what you need is [SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm), the Salesforce Object Search Language. Note however that SOSL is quite different from SOQL. See the linked developer guide for more information.